# How to convert a coloured image according to the colorfunction I defined?

Tags: color, image

I got an image from a website which follows the colorfunction "Rainbow", e.g.

```
example = DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 1200}, {y, 0, 1200}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Frame -> None]
```

I would like to use the following colour function for the image "example":

```
cfun[x_] := Blend[{{0, White}, {1, GrayLevel[0.2]}}, x];
Needs["PlotLegends`"];
legendraster = Rasterize[
 Graphics[
 Legend[cfun, 101, LegendShadow -> None, LegendSize -> {1, 1}, 
 LegendBorder -> None]], ImageSize -> 400, RasterSize -> 1200];
 curlegend = 
 Graphics[{Inset[legendraster, Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{0, 0}], 
 Scaled[{1, 1}]]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

My question is: How to convert the image (.jpg) with colorfunction "Rainbow" to a new image with the second colourfunction? (I can only import this .jpg into mathematica). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Let us plot something interesting:

```
img = Rasterize@DensityPlot[Cos[ArcTan[y, x] + x^2 + y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Frame -> None, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Correspondence function

```
f = Nearest@Table[List @@ Blend["Rainbow", x] -> List @@ cfun@x, {x, 0, 1, 0.003}];
```

Now we can convert colors (use `First@f@# &` for V9 and earlier)

```
ImageApply[First@*f, img]
```

[image]

It is very close to the reference image (except the border, which transforms from white to gray)

```
ref = Rasterize@DensityPlot[Cos[ArcTan[y, x] + x^2 + y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   ColorFunction -> cfun, Frame -> None, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

---

To deal with borders and axes you can use the following  function (use `{x,x,x}` instead of `{x}` for the colored functions)

```
f = Nearest@Flatten@Table[{List @@ Blend["Rainbow", x] -> 
      List @@ cfun@x, {x, x, x} -> {x}}, {x, 0, 1, 0.003}];

img2 = Rasterize@DensityPlot[Cos[ArcTan[y, x] + x^2 + y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

```
ImageApply[First@*f, img2]
```

[image]

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I want. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`Import` allows you to select the graylevel information directly from the JPEG data. In this case, you can apply a custom colorfunction:

```
ArrayPlot[Import["ExampleData/coneflower.jpg", "GrayLevels"], AspectRatio -> 1, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{0, RGBColor[159, 0, 255, 1]}, {1, GrayLevel[0.2]}}, #1] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your post. The issue is that the image I obtained from the website is a ".jpg" image with Rainbow colorfunction. One can only import it into mathematica. There is no such simple choice on changing Colorfunction. What I would like is that e.g. convert the image "example" into a grey image...